# When trying to use sshpass command with alias, getting Permission denied response

Tags: ssh, terminal, ssh-tunnel, sshpass

When I am trying to make a normal `sshpass` command in my terminal it is working correctly. This is the command I am using:

```
sshpass -p 'Rito$pass@20' ssh 'user.name@mysite.com'
```

When I am trying to use the same command by creating an alias, it is responding `Permission denied, please try again.`

I have created my alias in `.profile` file. This is how my alias looks:

```
alias myalias="sshpass -p 'Rito$pass@20' ssh user.name@mysite.com"
```

Can anyone please explain why I am getting Permission denied error when I am trying to use the alias, and how to resolve it?

=================================================================

## Update:

Based on @pynexj comment I ran the command `set -x; myalias; set +x` and found that the characters post `$` are not getting considered in the password. My password was `Rito$pass@20` but it was considering only `Rito@20`, that is all the characters after including the $ is ignored till the @ character.

Comment: `ssh-pass` is far than a smart solution. Consider using ssh key pairs instead. There's tons of tutorials on the web

Comment: try `set -x; myalias; set +x` and see what's wrong.

Comment: @pynexj I think I got the issue but don't know how to fix it. So when I ran the above mentioned command, the whole `sshpass` command gets printed which I have set in my alias. But I see the password which is getting printed is not correct. My password is `Rito$pass@20` but it prints `Rito@20`, that is all the characters after including the `$` is ignored till the `@` character. Any idea why it is happening and how to resolve it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment, there's a `$` char in the password. So to fix you need to escape the `$` char.

For example if the password is `pa$$word`:

```
alias myalias="sshpass -p 'pa\$\$word' ssh user.name@mysite.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

if your password contains special characters such as $... eg abcd@1234$$ then use \ with the special character....add this \ before each $$....it worked for me....
in your case add \ before $ or \ after o in 'Rito$pass@20'